# Ограничение сеанса в Winbox

Tags: mikrotik

Возможно ли ограничить сеанс соединения с Mikrotik в Winbox (что бы при истечении определенного времени, Winbox прерывал соединение с устройством)? И если возможно то как?

Comment: через радиус можно пропробовать

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите изменить количество времени, по истечении которого пользователи будут отключены из-за бездействия:

- `IP` → `Hotspot` → `User Profiles`
- Дважды щелкните запись `default`

**Session Timeout** - определяет, сколько времени должно пройти, пока клиент, подключенный к точке доступа, безоговорочно отключится. По истечении этого времени пользователю нужно будет снова войти в систему.

**Keepalive Timeout** – проверяет, подключен ли пользователь к роутеру, а если нет - отключает его. По сути, это означает, что он определяет, как долго авторизованный пользователь будет оставаться в точке доступа как авторизованный, даже если он временно покинет площадку. По истечении установленного времени пользователь будет отключен, и ему нужно будет снова войти в систему.

**Idle Timeout** – определяет, сколько времени должно пройти, когда пользователь неактивен (трафик не идет от пользователя к маршрутизатору), чтобы его отключили.